# Etherscan Verification when using a ContractFactory

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan, contract-verification

If I have a contract (ContractFactory) that creates several instances of some other contract (SubContract), is there a way to verify all instances of SubContract?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract ContractFactory {
    address[] public deployed;

    function createSubContract() public {
        deployed.push(new SubContract());
    }
}
contract SubContract {
    uint public var1;
    uint public var2;

    function SubContract() public {
        var1 = 1;
        var2 = 10000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy a contract with identical bytecode to one that's already verified on Etherscan, the new copy of the contract is also already verified.

Comment: I thought so too, but it's not happening, at least on Ropsten etherscan.  I deployed one SubContract using the above code, verified it, and then deployed several others. Non are verified.

Comment: Interesting. Is the code in your post the actual code? I think that if you use constructor parameters, different values for the parameters will require separate verification.

Comment: Yes, I used that exact code because I figured constructor params could get in the way.

Comment: I personally haven't tried this exact scenario. Can you link to the `ContractFactory` on ropsten.etherscan.io?

Comment: Here's a factory: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x0aafb9a374205ba022fd69d5f96101ae7b954bc3

Comment: And here's a SubContract I just deployed: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x4924e2d8d22c11072c1dd8f8d7363429d86fc374

Comment: Here's another SubContract I deployed (and verified): https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x826375ad8049909f5e55d2bfa851c229ac91af41#code

Comment: And, lastly, here's one more SubContract I deployed right after: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x213b523f7cffe09f8f9ee2cebd6d565dfa6a6d32

Comment: Odd. They all seem to have identical bytecode, but verifying one didn't verify the others. I'd recommend reaching out to etherscan.io to find out why.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm going to give it a few hours. Perhaps there's some caching mechanism for verified contracts that is not instant.